# Is this stack exchange suitable for questions concerning wireless communications?

Tags: support

Is EE.SE the right place to ask a question related to wireless communications and digital communications? Or is there another website that better fits this type of questions?

Comment: couldn't do that I need at least 5 points in my reputation @TronicZomB

Comment: This isn't the right place to ask if communications are on-topic. However, this is the place to ask about communications.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in meta.

Comment: @Tyrone forgot about that...

Comment: @embedded.kyle please dont :(

Comment: Closing just helps the signal to noise ratio of the site. This question doesn't belong here. Really, you should delete it yourself and ask your actual question because it does, in fact, belong here.

Comment: Ask the question and see? Generally as long as there's a hardware or radio-theory part to it I would say "yes".

Comment: I agree with @pjc50 - there are plenty of questions on this subject on EE.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon A quick reading of the help center would be a good substitute...

Comment: @MattYoung As would going to another site, reading relevant books, or taking up golf instead. So what?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The site has rules. Do you get some kind of enjoyment out of fighting them?

Comment: @MattYoung My actions on behalf of relative newcomers are invariably aimed at making their initial experiences reasonable enough that they choose to stay and become valued members of the community. I'd hope that that would be evident enough from what I actually say, but, maybe not to all. The site has a code of decent behaviour which is more honoured in the breach than the observance. The pedantic and ultra rapid implementation of actions [that could often (not always) be put off for a small while with net gain all round] makes it hard for newcomers to get their foot in the door.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I'm not certain, but I think that just prevents *initiating* a question or answer post, not necessarily banning editing or commenting. Trying to verify.

Answer (score 2):

From our [help center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> ## What topics can I ask about here?
>
> This site is for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts. We ask and answer questions about electrical and electronics engineering topics, which include electronics, physical computing, and those working with microcontrollers, Arduinos and embedded systems. We feel the best Electronics Design questions have a schematic, links to pertinent datasheets or some source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific electronics design problem
> - the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
> - a communication scheme
> - the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
> - consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except * when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses
> - Programming software for a PC
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

So, not all questions concerning wireless communications are on topic. For example:

- I'm looking for a wireless transceiver chip - *off topic; shopping recommendation*
- Does the SuperPhone 23X support Wi-Fi on 5GHz? - *off topic; use of electronic devices rather than electronics design*

But, some questions are on topic:

- I'm having trouble with this code to interface the ESP8266 Wi-Fi module. I'm getting these results but I would expect this-and-that.
- I want to implement wireless communication with these specific requirements. What protocol suits my needs?

## Look around

There exists a [wireless](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) tag, as well as [communication](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) and [digital-communications](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-communications). Look around if your question has been asked before. Also have a look what kind of questions get closed and what kind of questions are well received.

Comment: Camil  - I find it immensely weird that queries such as your example re a transceiver IC are deemed off topic. I know that this is the case, but it makes little sense to be able to suggest designs that include specific components, but not legal to ask about which components may suit a particular design aim. Worse, pedantic rewording can transform such perfectly reasonable but disallowed questions into almost as reasonable but allowed questions.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I agree! But that's more stuff for a discussion question, here I wanted to show the current state.